# sql - concatenate date and time into date field

Tags: php, sql, oracle

The date comes from a form and so does the time which is limited to 4 characters in 24 hour format. Trying to concatenate these values together and update a DATE field in the DB with both the date and time together... any ideas

I am getting weird outputs for the time... something other than what I input...

This captures a value from a textbox where someone can only insert a 24 HHMM time...

```
$form1 = $_SESSION['moviedate'];
$form2 = $_POST['screentime']; 


$sql = oci_parse($con, "Update schemaA.tableA SET SCREEN=to_date(:dmovie||:stime, 'DD-MON-YY HH24MI') WHERE ID=5");


oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':dmovie', $form1);
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':stime', $form2);


$obj = oci_execute($sql, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: 'Weird' isn't very helpful. Do you have an example of entry and result? Do you get an error? If not how are you querying to see what was set in the table? Having a space between the bind variables would be nice but not crucial. Does the date entry match the format model you're using? And why two-digit years?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this one:

```
$sql = oci_parse($con, "Update schemaA.tableA SET SCREEN=to_date(:date, 'DD-MON-YY HH24MI') WHERE ID=5");
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':date', $form1 . " " . $form2);
```

Are you sure that format of provided date is **always** `DD-MON-YY` (include proper language of month name)? Is the time always 4 digits?